# How do I scan each consecutively entered data point into subsequent nodes in a linear linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm doing this as a part of a beginner C programming course, and I am trying to debug using print statements. The assignment is as follows:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
/* A program that takes in user input providing name, symbol, and atomic weight of first 10 elements from a table,  then prints that data out.
   By John
   January 17 2022
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element
{
    char * name;
    char * symbol;
    float * weight;
} element;

typedef struct list
{
    element data;
    struct list* next;
} list;


list * create_list(char * name, char * symbol, float * weight_ptr)
{
    list * head = malloc(sizeof(list));
    head -> data.name = name;
    head -> data.symbol = symbol;
    head -> data.weight = weight_ptr;
    head -> next = NULL;
    return head;
}

list * add_to_front(char * name, char * symbol, float * weight_ptr, list * head)
{
    list * h;
    h = create_list(name, symbol, weight_ptr);
    printf("\nold head name = %s\n\nnew head name = %s\n\n",
             head -> data.name, h -> data.name);
    h -> next = head;
    return h;
}


list * info_to_list(char * name, char * symbol, float * weight_ptr)
{ 
    /* char * name;
    char * symbol;
    float weight; */
    list * head;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name:");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter the symbol:");
        scanf("%s", symbol);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter the weight:");
        scanf("%f", weight_ptr);
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            head = create_list(name, symbol, weight_ptr);
        }
        else        
        {
            printf("inside info to list function, name in prior head is: %s",
                    head -> data.name);
            head = add_to_front(name, symbol, weight_ptr, head);        
            printf("\ninside info to list function: name in new first head: %s\n",
                     head -> data.name);
        }
    } 
    return head;
}

void print_list(list * h)
{
    while(h != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nName: %s\n", h -> data.name);
        printf("Symbol: %s\n", h -> data.symbol);
        printf("Weight: %.3f\n\n", *(h -> data.weight));    
        h = h -> next;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    list * head;
    //float weight = 0.0;

    int name_size = 15; //no element name in first 10 reaches even 14 characters
    int symbol_size = 3; // symbol size up to  2 letters plus 1 for sentinel
    //int float_size = 30;

    char * name = (char *)malloc(name_size * sizeof(char));
    char * symbol = (char *)malloc(symbol_size * sizeof(char));
    //float * weight_ptr = (float *) malloc(float_size * sizeof(float));
    float * weight_ptr = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float));

    head = info_to_list(name, symbol, weight_ptr);
    print_list(head);

    free(head);
    free(name);
    free(symbol);
    free(weight_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

however when I compile and run this code, whenever I enter an element name, for example, Hydrogen, the printed statements say that the element name in the old "head" is hydrogen, and in the new "head" in hydrogen. How can I ensure that each consecutive element name I enter is scanned into each consecutive node in the linked list?

In the add_to_front function, my understanding is that I am passing the old head as an argument, and creating a new head, and inserting the newly input info from the console to the new head, hence I should have the old element info in the old head, and the new one in the new head, however that is not the case.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to make a copy of the string data to point to, instead of a pointer to the input buffer, which gets overwritten by the next input. For the symbol, which is 1 or two characters, it is unnecesary work to allocate a new buffer when the struct member could be, say, `char symbol[4];` but watch out for buffer overflow.

Comment: Common error. `head -> data.symbol = symbol;` is using the same `symbol` buffer for every node. Need to make a copy. For example `head -> data.symbol = strdup(symbol);`

Comment: also learn to use a debugger rather than printf statements, its much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commentators guided me to the right answer(s). Basically I needed to allocate pointees to the pointers that are head ->data.name, head ->data.symbol, and head ->data.weight, other than having them point to the buffers, which was my original mistake. I did that as follows:

```
 list * create_list(char * name, char * symbol, float * weight_ptr)
{
    list * head = malloc(sizeof(list));

    head -> data.name = strdup(name);
    head -> data.symbol = strdup(symbol);
    float local_weight = *weight_ptr;
    head -> data.weight = &local_weight;     
    head -> next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```